# Soap UI-Data driven testing-Apache POI error

Tags: java, excel, api, apache-poi, soapui

I am trying to run data driven excel in Soap UI using Apache POI,but getting error as

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap" error.

Below is the code:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

def fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\Soap\\New file.xlsx")
def wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs)
def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberofRows()

for(def i=0; i<r ; i++)
{
    def row = ws.getRow(i)
    def c = row.getPhysicalNumberofCells()

    for(def j = 0;j<c;j++)
    {
        def cell = row.getCell(j)
        log.info cell.getStringCellValue()
    }
}
```

Comment: [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components) needs `commons-collections` as a prerequisite but this lacks in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all dependencies of your Groovy script into the *bin/ext* directory within your SoapUI installation.

In this case, download Commons Collections library, unpack the archive and put the jar file into *bin/ext* directory.

You need to restart SoapUI afterwards.